# Can you use a loop-to-loop going braid to mono/fluoro?

Tags: knots, fishing

I have been using a double uni knot to go from braid to a fluoro leader, and just recently learned a perfection loop, and accompanying loop-to-loop for fly line to fly leader. For spinning gear with a variety of bass fishing tackle and line, would the perfection loop work in braid to quickly swap leaders that are not braid?

Comment: I know this is an old question and answer, but it got bumped to the front page since it was edited.  I'm wondering if you had pics or even a drawing?  It's difficult to understand what you are doing without one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verdict is that it works and seems to be very strong, but it is not easy to quickly switch leaders, since the braid-half of the loop-to-loop tightens around it itself much more than the mono/fluoro side of the loop.